# How do I store a list of preferences for a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm very new to ruby and rails so this is probably quite a simple question but very confusing to me.

I have users (with model, controller, views and everything all set up already). Now I want to introduce something where users can indicate what their preferences are. An example would be for users to indicate what their 5 favourite foods are, and then for me to be able to search for users by favourite food.

This being my first rails project, I'm a little unsure how to approach this. My thoughts so far:

1) Add a boolean array to my User model, render the array as checkboxes and then store it somehow. (I'm just not sure how to generate the migration for that, or how to search by food item if implemented like that).

2) Create a Food model and use the `has_many` relationship in my User model to link users to foods. I imagine I'd then be able to search for users based on a food?  I feel like a Food model might be overkill because it's not something that has any information relating to it. It is just something to attach to Users.

Any suggestions, code, hints or tips would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should use http://railscasts.com/ as a resource. Everything that you're describing here, this site has tutorials on.

You want to be careful adding several fields to your user model (ie fav_food_one, fav_food_two, etc) since searching and returning lists will be troublesome.

You more likely would want something where you have a has_many associations

```
User: username, name, email, etc

Food: name, category, fun_facts, etc

UserFavoriteFoods: user_id:integer, food_id:integer
```

In your models, you would create an association like this.

```
User=> 
  has_many :user_favorite_foods, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :foods, :through => :user_favorite_foods

Food=>
  has_many :user_favorite_foods, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :user_favorite_foods  

UserFavoriteFoods =>
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :food
```

Then in your (i'm assuming User#Show) view, you could do something like this

```
<% @user.foods.each do |food| %>
 <li><%= food.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

Edit=>

You can also use a gem like `simple_form` and apply it to your user form.

Using `f.association :foods` in this kind of list would bring up a select box automatically and allow your user to easily select the different food items.

Comment: Thanks so much for the railscasts.com link. That's super helpful. What I wanted was here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes?autoplay=true